# how to record audio?

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to record audio by using the following code.

[android-audio-recording-tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)

when i call start record it is working fine.

But when i call stop recod recording it throws error message like the fallowing.

```
 ..............................................................

 11-14 18:03:28.361: V/tag(23349): outgoing call ended
 11-14 18:03:28.361: V/tag(23349): record.111.android.media.MediaRecorder@4052de80
 11-14 18:03:28.371: E/MediaRecorder(23349): stop called in an invalid state: 1
 11-14 18:03:28.371: D/AndroidRuntime(23349): Shutting down VM
 11-14 18:03:28.371: W/dalvikvm(23349): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught      exception (group=0x40015560)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.Audio.CallsBrodcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at com.example.Audio.AudioRecorder.stop(AudioRecorder.java:64)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at com.example.Audio.CallsBrodcastReceiver.onReceive(CallsBrodcastReceiver.java:147)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
 11-14 18:03:28.381: E/AndroidRuntime(23349):   ... 10 more
```

if any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add your stop condition in try n catch block.. you might callin in wrong state. chck out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try this code for start and stop recording of sounds in android.

public class SoundRecordingActivity extends Activity {

    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File audiofile = null;
    private static final String TAG = "SoundRecordingActivity";
    private View startButton;
    private View stopButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startButton = findViewById(R.id.start);
        stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop);
    }

    public void startRecording(View view) throws IOException {

        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);

        File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try {
            audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", sampleDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
            return;
        }
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording(View view) {
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
    }

    protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
Add this permissions in Manifest And Let me know the status?
```